# NPGSQL MapEnum fails after EF migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I added an `enum` to entity framework and registered it with NPGSQL, [as per docs](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/enum.html?tabs=tabid-1):

```cs
static DataContext()
{
    NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<MyEnum>();
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ForNpgsqlHasEnum<MyEnum>();
    ...
}
```

After running migrations and starting up the web application, the following exception is thrown:

> The CLR enum type MyEnum must be registered with Npgsql before usage, please refer to the documentation

If I restart the application again, it works just fine - this only occurs immediately after the migration in which `MyEnum` was added is applied.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that NPGSQL's type mapping gets out of sync with the database after migrations occur, and [types need to be reloaded after migrations are performed](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/292).

This can be rectified by calling `ReloadTypes()` after calling `Migrate()`:

```cs
public void Migrate()
{
    Database.Migrate();

    using (var connection = (NpgsqlConnection)Database.GetDbConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        connection.ReloadTypes();
    }
}
```